# Display Status of Classes

Tags: c#

I have a Windows Form that calls a number of methods in 2 separate classes in a single dll.

In the Form I want to display status updates i.e. display in label how the query is progressing.

How do I track the status of methods of 2 different classes in dll?

Thanks!

Below is sample dll code...

```
public class ClassA
{

    private string ProgressStatus
    private void SetStatusText(string currentStatus)
    {
        progressStatus = currentStatus;
    }

    public void ReportRequest()
    {   
        SetStatusText("Begin Process..."); // update status

  SetStatusText("Getting Dates..."); // update status

        // get dates
  DatesClass myDates = new DatesClass()
        datesOK = myDates.GetDates();

        if (datesOK)
        {
    SetStatusText("Running Request...");
    RunFinalRequest();
        }
    }
}


public internal class ClassB
{

    private string ProgressStatus
    private void SetStatusText(string currentStatus)
    {
        progressStatus = currentStatus;
    }


    public string GetDates()
    {   

    SetStatusText("Loading Dates..."); // update status

          LoadDates();

          return // return sql query value
    }

    private void LoadDates()
    {
    // sql query...
    SetStatusText("Run Query...");
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need a status of a method execution rather than `status of classes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). You'd create two background worker classes and have them run your methods. You can then use the `ProgressChanged` event to report progress back to your original thread.

Comment: so I have a BackGroundWorker in each class of the dll?

Comment: Think of your two classes that report their progress as "workers". You have two background workers in your application, one for each worker. Your workers can then report their progress at any point, and the UI thread will be notified that there was a progress report. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: Hi,I am a little confused. Any quick example of this? Thanks!

Comment: I'm just going to end up Googling for "backgroundworker tutorial". I'd recommend you do the same.

Comment: Yes but is it 2 backgroundworkers in the Windows Form? Or inside the dll? 
Also the Windows Form will not be able to access ClassB - this Class is restricted and can only be called through ClassA.